# Why can't I login with Google in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

When I click on the button, I see my Google accounts, and when I click on one of the accounts, I see this:

[image: img]

Terminal:

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error expected 200 OK, got: 403 Forbidden {
  error: OPError: expected 200 OK, got: 403 Forbidden
      at async Client.validateIdToken (D:\my next js app\my-app\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:745:49)
      at async Client.callback (D:\my next js app\my-app\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:488:7)
      at async oAuthCallback (D:\my next js app\my-app\node_modules\next-
      at async DevServer.handleRequest (D:\my next js app\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-
...

server.js:322:20) {
    name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
    code: undefined
  },
  providerId: 'google',
  message: 'expected 200 OK, got: 403 Forbidden'
}
```

This is my `[...nextauth].js` file:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

This is my `.env` file:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=something.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=something-
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
JWT_SECRET=something
```

This is my button:

```
         const { data: session } = useSession();


          {session ? (
            <h1>You are signed in {session.user.email}</h1>
          ) : (
            <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => signIn('google')}>
              Login
            </Button>
          )}
```

Why can't I login with Google in Next.js?

Comment: Do you have set the URL in callback?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but I found that you could solve it by adding `browserPopupRedirectResolver` as a third parameter in the `signInWithPopup()` function

Your code should be:

```js
import { browserPopupRedirectResolver } from "firebase/auth";

const result = await signInWithPopup( FirebaseAuth, googleProvider, browserPopupRedirectResolver );
```

Comment: Where should this code be added? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

for me , i **set a public dns** on my network , and it's working